# Silence post-build events in Visual Studio output window

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, post-build-event

When building solutions, post build events are displayed verbose, unless I put `> NUL` after every command.

**Is there a way to silence all successful post-build commands?**

Otherwise, the log seems *very* verbose, from the quantity of commands executed.

[image: Post Build]

Comment: That looks like xcopy.exe output.  Suppressing its output is pretty easy, you put `> NUL` after the command.  Open door => kick.

Comment: As I stated in the question, yes. I could put `> NUL` after every command. But is there a way to completely omit successful commands?